# Does PPO clip kills gradient

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, proximal-policy-optimization, reward-clipping

In PPO Loss function, the reasoning to use the clip function is to do the update within a trusted region. But **once we use the clip function, don't it kills the gradients with it?** Because the only place it has gradient is the $\pi_\theta(a|s)$, and if we clip it, there is no way to get the gradient.

So, **does this means, model will not learn anything from the instances where the loss get clipped?**

It is briefly mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769111/does-ppos-gradient-clipping-really-prevent-r%CE%B8-from-exceeding-1%C2%B1epsilon). But, I could not find another source that verifies this. And Chat-GPT thinks it does not kills the gradients.

Thank you.

Comment: According to this [hugging face tutorial](https://huggingface.co/blog/deep-rl-ppo#the-intuition-behind-ppo) the answer is yes (see the table). That being said the table originally came from a master's thesis so it's not as reliable as a scientific paper. Also ChatGPT is pretty bad with technical details, consider any non-obvious answer it gives to be a guess.